# Print sum of n numbers in plsql

Tags: plsql, sum, plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printsum(n IN number) IS
res number:=0;
BEGIN
while(n>0)
LOOP
res:=res+n;
n:=n-1;
EXIT WHEN n=0;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line(' result of sum: '||res);
END;
/
```

I'm trying to print sum of n numbers, but I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code.

1) `Function` must have a `Return` but your code had missing `Return` statement at beginning and at end.

2) `IN` parameter cannot be reassigned inside the code. So you need to copy the `IN` parameter to a variable to iterate.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION printsum( n IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    res   NUMBER:=0;
    v_num NUMBER:=n;
  BEGIN        
    WHILE(v_num>0)
    LOOP
      res   := res   + v_num;
      v_num := v_num -1;
      EXIT  WHEN v_num=0;        
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line(' result of sum: '||res);

    RETURN(res);      
  END;
  /
```

Output:

```
SQL> select printsum(10) from dual;

PRINTSUM(10)
------------
          55
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. number strictly speaking is not necessarily integral so best to use pls_integer or at least check in the code that the passed in argument is integral
2. if the question is asking how to return the sum of the first n positive integers, the correct answer is to used the closed form formula: n * (n + 1)/2

Using the formula gives you a constant time answer.

```
function printsum(n pls_integer) return n is
begin
  if(n < 0) then raise value_error; end if; -- or a more meaningful exception
  return (n * (n + 1) / 2);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is the solution:

```
declare
  sm number;
  tmp number;
  n number;
  i number;
function sumn(n integer)
return number
is
sm number;
begin
   sm:=0;
tmp:=n;
for i in 1..tmp LOOP
    sm:=sm+i;
END LOOP;
return sm;
END;
begin
   n:=10;
   sm:=sumn(n);
    dbms_output.put_line('sum is',sm);
end;
/
```